# How to increase window edge resize grabbing distance in Xfce?

Tags: windows, mouse, tui

I have to struggle with the mouse cursor, to grab **the exact window edge or corner pixel** in order to resize. The bandwith of how far the mouse can be from the exact window edge feels like less than three pixels, which is unpleasantly low.

How to I increase that draggable area?

Preferrably without necessarily altering the window borders.

Comment: Alt+MiddleClick and Alt+RightClick is also an excellent solution I just found, so it is now less important. Would not be bad, however, if I could increase the window corner/edge grabbable area. **Customizability** is a part of Linux philosophy, and Android just pretends to be customizable (they're more customizeable than iOS, but not sufficiently customizeable to give me the green battery icon).

Comment: How about trying the key combination of `Alt+Space, R` for resize, then you just start pressing the arrow keys in the direction you want to grow.

Comment: I have the same experience and it looks like it depends on the the used theme.

Comment: @mook765 so which is a nice theme that allows you to use the mouse more easily to resize windows without changing border thickness?

Comment: @DK Bose Currently I use `NOX`-theme, there are some other glitches though, in some cases text and background don't have much contrast, but only a few cases...

Answer (score 6):

Try Windows Manager by scrolling through the themes.

- Settings
- Windows Manager
- Theme

You will notice a thickening or slimming of the window edge as you pick a different theme. Pick one that has thick edge because that means grabbing the edge to resize the window becomes easier.

Comment: This worked!  I am surprised no one else has up-voted this solution.  Thank you @Ofoe.  I was going crazy.  My default theme was 'Greybird'.  This did not work.  I switched to 'Default-xhdpi and now have no problem finding the edge of a window.

Comment: Thanks for the solution.  It would be even better if there were a simple way to customize the theme of your choice to fix this virtual bug.

Comment: I want thin border (like in other OSes, or even like in KDE) but thick 'area' to grab the border

Comment: In Ubuntu Mate 22.04, I opened Control Center, then Appearance, Theme, Custom, Customize, Window Border, Atlanta.  This gave me more "grab area".

Answer (score 5):

You can not.
All maintainers of all Linux distros, afaik, are proud to have them so tiny. User experience does NOT count. This annoying problem has been asked multiple times - no GUI maintainer seems interested.

"Solution"

Alt+right mouse = resize (most of the time)

Alt+ left mouse = move (no resize)

Comment: yeah, that's a problem with most linuxes, build for taking screenshots of your desktop, not for productivity :/

Comment: Well, I do not get the sarcasm part: Grabbing faster would certainly improve productivity. We are talking "grabbable part of window" i.e. mouse context NOT fat bold window edges.

Comment: @Michael as for the sarcasm part, the problem is that moving my other hand does not increase the productivity in case I use only one hand.

Comment: also using executing `Alt-right mouse hold` on a notebook touchpad is not easy ...